# how do I get rid of sql injection in this case

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, sql-injection

I have a method like this in my RoR 3 app

```
  def buscar
    array = params[:query].split(' ')
    array.each_with_index  do |query, index|
      array[index] = array[index].gsub(/<\/?[^>]*>/, "").downcase
    end
    @noticias = Noticia.where(:tags.all => array).paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end
```

I'm using `brakeman` to scan for any problems, and he says this

`Possible SQL injection near line 116: Noticia.where(:tags.all => (params[:query].split(" ")))`

How can I change the query to evict this problem?
Oh, i'm using mongoid
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried splitting the params hash into a variable and then running each against find_by_tag and building your @noticias that way?

Comment: nope...how do I do that? I didn't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but something like this:

```
tag = params[:query].split(" ")
tag.each do |tag|
  @noticias << Noticias.find_by_tag(tag)
end
@noticias.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

You may have to mess with the `<<`. I'm not sure what paginate looks for in the @noticias object.

Comment: that did the trick. thanks a lot. but how do I paginate these results...I was using `pagiante` before, and now, I'm searching by each tag. there is no `paginate` anymore

Comment: `@noticias.paginate(:page => params[:page])`

Comment: i've added this scope: `scope :tag, ->(name){ where(tags: name) }` and my `buscar` is like  `array.each do |tag|
      @noticias << Noticia.tag(tag)
    end` but i'm getting undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @Luiz, I'd open up a new question.